# Can't mount mailbox database

Tags: exchange-2007

After replacing a harddisk and copying my Exchange database files I cannot mount them.
Before copying them I stopped the Exchange Storage service so my databases are clean. But when I try to mount them I get the error
MapiExceptionCallFailed: Unable to mount database. (hr=0x80004005, ec=-546)

I already tried several things (including various eseutil runs) but the error persists.

I also tried to restore a backup of the database (using Windows Server Backup). After the restore I got the error "Unable to read the log file header. Error -546"

Comment: `After replacing a harddisk and copying my Exchange database files I cannot mount them.` - Where are your Exchange aware backups?

Comment: I also restored a backup of the database (using Windows Server Backup). After the restore I get the error "Unable to read the log file header. Error -546".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be a different size for the new disk. The old disk (4TB) was likely emulating 512 bytes sectors while the new disk (RAID10) is 2048 bytes sectors. I did try to store the database on an old 2TB drive but that was **real** 512 bytes sectors so the error persistet.

After reading https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/2943-find-and-replay-missing-log-files-in-exchange I just moved all log files to another folder and was then able to mount the databases.

Now I could see the mails in the folder view but all mails were reported as missing.
I ran **isinteg.exe** and it fixed a lot of errors. After that everything seems to be ok, I'm only missing a couple of mails from the last days.